# List all post with each terms created, nested in another term

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type: 'course'.
Inside 'course' are 2 taxonomies:

1. 'course_type' (Full Time Courses, Part Time Courses)
2. 'course_attribute' (Business, Design, Hospitality)

How can I list all posts along with all 'course_attribute' as headers?
I want the list to appear as:

**Full Time Courses**

*Business*

- Business Course 01
- Business Course 02

*Design*

- Design Course 01
- Design Course 02

*Hospitality*

- Hospitality Course 01
- Hospitality Course 02

**Part Time Courses**

*Business*

- Business Course 01
- Business Course 02

*Design*

- Design Course 01
- Design Course 02

*Hospitality*

- Hospitality Course 01
- Hospitality Course 02

Current code is not really working as I expected it to be and it is not hiding course types that are empty.

```html
<?php 
$terms = get_terms( 'course_attributes', array(
    'orderby'    => 'count',
    'hide_empty' => true
    ) );
    ?>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <h2>Full Time Courses</h2>
    <?php
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        $args = array(
            'hide_empty' => true,
            'post_type' => 'course',
            'course_attributes' => $term->slug,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'course_type',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'full-time-courses',
                    'hide_empty' => true
                    )
                ),
            );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        echo'<p><strong>' . $term->name . '</strong></p>';
        echo '<ul>';
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <li class="" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile;
    echo '</ul>';
    wp_reset_postdata();
    } ?>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
    <h2>Part Time Courses</h2>
    <?php
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'course',
            'course_attributes' => $term->slug,

            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'course_type',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'part-time-courses',
                    )
                ),
            );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        echo'<p><strong>' . $term->name . '</strong></p>';
        echo '<ul>';
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <li class="" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile;
    echo '</ul>';
    wp_reset_postdata();
    } ?>

</div>
```